# Speed up ETL transformation - Pentaho Kettle

Tags: database, mongodb, cassandra, pentaho, etl

For a project, I have to deal with many sensors Time Series data.

I have an industrial machine that produces some artifacts. For each work (max 20  mins in time) sensors record oil pressure and temperature, and some other vibrational data (very high frequencies). All these Time Series are recorded in a .csv file, one for each sensor and for each work. Each file is named:

```
yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm_ss_sensorname.csv
```

and contains just a sequence of real numbers.

I have to store somehow this kind of data. I am benchmarking many solution, relational and not, like MySQL, Cassandra, Mongo, etc.

In particular, for Cassandra and Mongo, I am using **Pentaho Data Integration** as ETL tool.

I have designed a common scheme for both DBs (unique column family/collection):

```
---------------------------------------
id | value | timestamp | sensor | order
---------------------------------------
```

The problem is that I am forced to extract timestamp and sensor information from filenames, and I have to apply many transformation to have the desired formats.

This slows my whole job down: uploading a single work (with just a single high-frequency metric, for a total of 3M rows, more or less) takes **3 mins** for MongoDB, **8 mins** for Cassandra.

I am running both DBs on a single node (for now), with 16 GB RAM and an 15 Core CPU.

I am sure I am doing the transformation wrong, so the question is: how can I speed things up??

Here is my KTR file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaJah.jpg (not enough rep to post images)

Comment: I cannot read your ktr file (a null pointer exception along the way). Can you publish an image ?

Comment: For sure. Updated!

Comment: As you can see, timestamp, id, sensor, order fields are computed and added for each row. While this is OK for id and order, timestamp and sensor are the same for all the rows in the same .csv file. I would like some way to calculate them from filename just once, and in the end add them to each row.

Comment: I cannot read your first input step. `CSV input`? `Text file input`? The reason of this question is that the `Text file input` accepts filename from a previous step, while the `CSV input` does not.

Comment: It's a Text file Input step, but it is actually for a .csv file. CSV import step does not allow to remove headers and footers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot unfortunately use the filename which is on the `Additional output field` tab because this field is populated in parallel and there are chance it is not known when you use it in computations.

However, in your case, you can put the filename in a field, for example with a `data grid`, and use it for computations of timestamp and sensor. In parallel, you make the needed transforms on id, value and order. When finished you put them together again. I added a `Unique Row` on the common flow, just in case the input is buggy and have more than one timestamp, sensor.

[image]

Comment: Your solution was of great help. I did not think about joins.

Comment: Only one question left: using this flow, I cannot apply such a transformation to a list of file (specified in the input file step), because the join step will produce (#records * #files) rows. How can I apply this transf. to a list of file, one after another??

Comment: You'll need a for each Job > Ktr > Ktr solution. In the first KTR you'll use a get file names step with a copy rows to result, just those 2, in the second KTR you'll need to set a parameter 'filename'. In the Job configuration, for the second KTR you'll mark the advanced options 'copy previous results to parameters' and 'Execute for every input row', in this same config you'll set the same 'filename parameter' for both Parameter and Stream Coolumn. In the second KTR you'll use the ${filename} variable for CSV input. If you need an example i can provide.

Comment: Thanks Christian. You are right. Post it as an answer and I'll vote for it. However, this case is a special case where you can do it in one transformation only.

Comment: LucaF: Out the list of file in the data grid, and do not forget to check the `Accept file name from the previous step`.

Comment: AlainD - As i understand the data contained in the CSV files, need the timestamp and sensorname in the filename, as 2 columns in this new scheme. Do ALL the CSV files need to be read before the JOIN ? Or the entire process is done for each file separately. If it's separate, then the Job > Ktr > Ktr solution works, if all need to be read and joined, then this solution becomes a Ktr with a Transoformation Executor with the solution for each CSV file to run all files and return the full result of each, alltogether, before the Join.

Comment: Cristian - You are right. Perfectly right. The good practice is to use a job. However, this on a special case in which you can do simpler. The drawback of this solution is that you must read all the csv in order for the join to start passing data to the Cassandra output. Which, in this special case again, is a good thing. Because it will buffer the Cassandra in one bunch. The main issue of the OP.